# Display Products Group by Category and Sub category in WP E-Commerce

Tags: wordpress, product

I am having trouble with this presentation, I am using WP E-Commerce(Version 3.8.9.5).For example i am having the product page that I want to display is like this:

Category1
  Sub-Category 1
    Product1
    Product2
    Product3
  Sub-Category 2
    Product1
    Product2
    Product3
Category2
  Sub-Category 1
    Product1
    Product2
    Product3
  Sub-Category 2
    Product1
    Product2
    Product3

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Displaying sub-categories at the top of a product list page in WP e-Commerce is one of those things which seems totally common sense, but for which WP e-Commerce apparently has no real solution. I ended up creating a routine at the top of the theme’s WP e-Commerce template file to accomplish this.
To get the categories that a product is assigned to:

```
$categories = wp_get_object_terms ($post->ID, 'wpsc_product_category');
```

view this article -> [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-wp-e-commerce-how-can-i-display-the-categories-a-product-is-in)

or 
more complicated in this article -> [here](http://www.craniumstorm.com/wp-e-commerce-sub-category-display/)